# where to put break in switch/case statement with blocks

Tags: c++, syntax

When I use braces around `case` code block in C++ to localize variables should I put `break` inside or outside the block?

```
case FOO:  // 'break' inside
  {
    int i;
    doStuff();
    break;
  }

case BAR: // 'break' outside
  {
    int i;
    doStuff();
  }
  break;
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think it makes perfect sense

Comment: Makes sense as is, but a code example would none-the-less make it clearer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's a matter of style.

I would put `break` outside the closing brace just to make it more readable.

Comment: Agree. Disagree (I think its more readable inside, but that's just my style :-0  )

Answer (score 16):

You put it wherever you like. Make sure you stay consistent throughout the entire project. (Personally, I put it outside.)

Comment: I'm all for consistency, but it also depends on the code flow, and perhaps it may work better inside if more control is needed for whether or not to break.

Answer (score 6):

It should appear after.

For example:

```
switch(value)
{
   case 0:
   {
   // this ...
   // that ...
   // and the other ...
   }
   break;
}
```

**Edited text below**

This mostly to improve readability and maintainability here's an example.

```
switch (value)
{
   case 0:
    // Do this...
    // Do that...
    break;
   case 1:
    //and the other...
   break;
}
```

and

```
switch (value)
{
   case 0:
    // Do this...
    // Do that...
    if (ObjectWithinScope.Type == Fault)
    break;
   case 1:
    //and the other...
   break;
}
```

Now compare with

```
switch (value)
{
   case 0:
   {
    // Do this...
    // Do that...
   }
   break;
   case 1:
    //and the other...
   break;
}
```

and

```
   switch (value)
    {
       case 0:
       {
        // Do this...
        // Do that...
        if (ObjectWithinScope.Type == Fault)
        break;
       }
       case 1:
       {
        //and the other...           
       }
       break;
    }
```

When you start to come across cases of nested switch statements it can get very confusing indeed.

**Just a pointer.**

Now some of you are still wondering what I am getting at. Here it is. A piece of legacy code stopped working and noone could work out why. It all boiled down to a piece of code structured like the following:

```
   switch (value)
    {
       case 0:
       {
        // Do this...
        // Do that...
        if (ObjectWithinScope.Type == Fault)
        break;
       }
       case 1:
       {
        //and the other...           
       }
       break;
    }
```

It took a long time to pin down this code, but on checking the change logs it was originally as followws:

```
   switch (value)
    {
       case 0:
       {
        // Do this...
        // Do that...
        if (ObjectWithinScope.Type == Fault)
            // *** A line of code was here ***
        break;
       }
       case 1:
       {
        //and the other...           
       }
       break;
    }
```

Admittedly the original code wasn't consistant with itself, but by having the break within the curly brackets the code compiled when the one line of code was deleted by accident. If the break had been outside of the brackets then it wouldn't have.

Comment: By placing it after the block readability and maintainalbility of the code is clearer - I've edited my answer to show a case in point.

Answer (score 4):

I usually put the `break` inside the braces, like this:

```
switch (foo) {
    case bar: {
        int x = 5;
        printf("%d\n", x);
        break;
    }
    case baz: {
        // ...
        break;
    }
}
```

However, since it's my rule I'm free to break it (no pun intended) whenever I want.

Answer (score 4):

Everyone agrees that we want a clearly recognizable distinction between the `switch/case...` machinery and the actual actions performed in each case.

Therefor, unless there's really almost *nothing* going on in each case (simple assignment or so), I suggest to use the `switch` as a mere dispatcher, and delegate the 'real' things to helper functions.  That automatically solves the issue of case-local variables, and obsolesces the need for braces altogether.

```
switch( operation ) {
  case cnegation: r = -value; break;
  case cinversion: r = 1./r; break;
  case cfaculty: { 
    double r = value; 
    while( value != 1 ) 
      r *= --value; 
  }
  break;
}
```

Should then become

```
switch( operation ) {
  case cnegation : r = negate (value) ; break;
  case cinversion: r = invert (value) ; break;
  case cfaculty  : r = faculty(value) ; break;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but I think there is something important that can be added here: style matters not just for aesthetics, but can actually make a difference in helping to mistake-proof real software written by real, fallible, humans.

Although where to put the `break` statement is certainly a matter of style, not a requirement of the language, there is one convention I haven't seen mentioned here that if followed makes it much easier to read, write, and review `switch` statements while ensuring that there is never any unintended fall-through.

The style looks like this:

```
switch(variable) {
    break; case 1 : statement;
    break; case 2 : {
       code in a block;
    }
    break; case 3 : other statement;
    /****/ case 4 : fall-through here on purpose.
    break; default: default behavior;
}
```

Although you could argue this is just a minor stylistic variation, *in my experience* (with over 20 years of using this style in critical embedded system code) its much easier to both write, review and maintain this kind of code. The biggest reason is because it changes the conceptual thought model.

Instead of thinking: "in this condition, do a bunch of stuff which I have to think hard about ... *oh yeah, and then break or fall through*", it forces the thought process to be: "this is either a brand-new condition, or a fall through from the previous case; now, in this condition, do a bunch of stuff which I can think hard about, and then move on."

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the logic of your code and how it uses braces, but for the sake of a proper answer, if you put one inside, try to put all of them inside.

Answer (score 1):

On my opinion you should avoid local variables and blocks in switch statements. Also you should avoid long, or complex or even cascaded switch statements anyway.
But no rule without an exception ... I prefer to write the break statement after the block.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter as long as you and your team do the same thing consistently. Even then, it's not a big issue if different team members do it differently.

I personally prefer after. The reasoning is that it gives some separation between the machinery of the switch statement (jumping to, executing stuff and getting out), and the code within the braces which is purely involved with the 'doing' of the case.

eg:

```
switch( value )
{
    case 0:
        {
            // code here
        }
        break;

    default:
        {
            assert(!"unhandled value in switch");
        }
        break;
}
```

I only use {} for a case if it needs local variables, but if I use {} for any case, I put them on all cases.

I usually always define a default case to assert if there is any unexpected value. It's amazing how often one of these asserts fires to remind you of a missing case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like putting any sort of brackets in a switch statement. Personally if it's a complex operation, I like putting it in a function. There's nothing more annoying than seeing a switch statement where between each "case" there are hundreds of lines of code and on top of that some of them are repeated in various cases which makes maintenance impossible.

For example:

```
switch(blah)
{
 case 1:
  // do one thing
  break;

 case 2:
  doManyThings();
  break;

 default:  
  // something
  break;
}
```

Comment: Having a local variable inside case statement does not mean I have a complex statement with a lot of code inside.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter for style, but I put it after as I understand the definition as:

```
switch (variable)
{
    case expression:
        statement;
        break;
    default:
        statement;
        break;
}
```

where statement is either a single command or a block.  The break is separate to this statement or block. And yes, I do add a break after the default although it is superfluous.  I also ***ALWAYS*** put braces around the statement.  Too many times have I added one more statement to only to break the scope.  And I add break to the default as I have changed default: to case expression: and added something after it.  Defensive coding is your friend.

However, I can only find documentation for the actual definition via Microsoft as:

```
selection-statement:
    switch ( expression ) statement

labeled-statement:
    case constant-expression : statement
    default : statement
```

Which would indicate that it should be inside.

However, I think outside is clearer from a readers perspective, but it is certainly subjective.

Answer (score 0):

Since standard does not limit you in choosing position for `break` statement you could choose whatever you like. Personally I'm using the following style:

```
 switch ( some_var ) {
        case 1: {
            // lot of code here
        } break;
        case 2: /* one call */ break;
        case 3: /* one call */ break;
        case 4: {
            // lot of code here again
        } break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to be said for the style of only using one statement per case, and never using braces.  For example:

```
switch( cond ) {
default: foo(); break;
case 0: bar(); break;
case 1: baz(); break;
}
```

Using this style, your question is moot.

Comment: Why the downvote?  The question is purely about style, and this is an answer on style?

Answer (score 0):

**Real Answer:** Compiler doesn't care. It's a matter of preference.

I put them inside, like the [google style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Loops_and_Switch_Statements#Loops_and_Switch_Statements).

If using braces, I like the opening brace to be on the same column as the closing brace (which differs from google).

```
switch (var) {
  case 0: 
  {  
    ...      
    break;
  }
  case 1: 
  {
    ...
    break;
  }
  default: 
    assert(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My take... See here below for an example.

Indent all cases of a switch and have the closing bracket of the switch under the keyword `switch`, just like one would do in an `if` statement. Whenever needed, same rule for each `case` statement: open brackets after the semi-column following the `case` statement and close them under the keyword `case`, then indent the contents of each of the `case` statements including the keyword `break`.

Keep it consistent (indentation and brackets placements) and short (no more than 5-10 lines of code per `case` statement. Complex projects have failed because of badly indented `switch` statements with too much code in them.

```
    switch (number) {

        case 1:
            logFileStderr(VERBOSE, "MESSAGE: switch without brackets...\n");
            break;

        case 2: {
            logFileStderr(VERBOSE, "MESSAGE: switch with brackets...\n");
            break;
        }

        default:
            logFileStderr(VERBOSE, "WARNING: Unknown option...\n");
            break;
    }
```